# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Text size limit

Tags: web-services, configuration, cxf, woodstox

I am sending a big attachment to a CXF webservice and I get the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Text size limit (134217728) exceeded
>    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,134855131]]
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:426)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:769)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:94)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:797)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:795)
>       ... 25 more

The issue seems to come from the Woodstox library that says

> Text size limit (134217728) exceeded

Does someone know if it is possible to increase this limit? if yes, how to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's coming from woodstox like that, then you aren't sending it as an MTOM attachment.  My first suggestion would be to flip it to MTOM so it can be handled outside the XML parsing.  Much more efficient as we can keep it as an inputstream or similar and not have it in memory.

If you want to keep it in the XML, you can set the property:  "org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength" to some larger value.   Keep in mind, stuff coming in from the stax parser like this are held in memory as either a String or byte[] and will thus consume memory.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Just one last thing, if I want to set the property "org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength" to a given value, how should I do? using the system property -Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength=X will work?

Comment: Use the standard Stax property mechanism: `XMLInputFactory.setProperty()`. This feature was added in Woodstox 4.2, to help prevent denial-of-service attacks: defaults depend on framework that uses Woodstox (CXF in this case)